# If our axioms don't describe everything why don't we just add new ones?

Tags: logic, soft-question

In reading https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/what-are-some-reasonable-sounding-statements-that-are-independent-of-zfc?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top I began to wonder: if our axioms don't describe everything then why don't we just add new ones?

Why are we no longer looking for axioms that could help us solve polynomials degree 5?

Why have we (mostly) given up on proving the continuum hypothesis only because it is independent of our axioms?

I'm sure there are many other problems like these. I'm puzzled because a solution to them would be extremely useful, and the purpose of mathematics is ultimately to solve problems (unless you are a game formalist, of course ;)).

**Addition** I know no axioms are complete, but certainly some systems are better than others.

This is a soft question.

Comment: The continuum hypothesis can't be proved or disproved using ZFC. It can be proved with other sets of axioms, but most mathematicians believe there's no reason to accept it as true or false because it's independent and there's no obvious reason why it should be true or false.

Comment: Polynomial equations of degree $5$ can be solved by adding new operations in addition to radicals. This has been done.

Comment: @MattSamuel oh what are they

Comment: No amount of new axioms will enable you to find a general solution to a polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$ using radicals (assuming you want to keep the existing axioms). As for the continuum hypothesis, many axioms have been suggested that either imply it or deny it, but neither one is as "obvious" as the other axioms, so their acceptance is controversial.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Solution_of_the_general_quintic .

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn It can also be solved using elliptic functions. There are similarly solutions to sextic and septic equations, but they use transcendental functions.

Comment: Saying we can't "solve" quintic equations is like saying that white has won a chess game, any axiom set that could change that would be wrong (unsound).

Comment: See [Bertrand Russell](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Quotations/Russell.html): "The method of "postulating" what we want has many advantages; they are the same as the advantages of theft over honest toil. *Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy*, 1919, p 71."